# How can I solve this ODE: $u' + u (i q(x) - i \lambda) = 0$, where $q(x)$ is an arbitrary continuous function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE: $u' + u (i q(x) - i \lambda) = 0$?

The $q(x)$ is bothering me, because I don't know what to do here. We can't just say that it's $u = C e^{-(iq(x) - i\lambda)x}$, because $(-(iq(x) - i \lambda)x)' = -i q'(x)x - (iq(x) - i \lambda)$, so we'd get: $$C e^{-(iq(x) - i\lambda)x} \cdot (-i q'(x)x - (iq(x) - i \lambda)) + C e^{-(iq(x) - i\lambda)x} (iq(x) - i \lambda) = 0$$ $$C e^{-(iq(x) - i\lambda)x} \cdot (-i q'(x)x) = 0$$

Comment: Find an integrating factor.

Comment: @HansEngler And how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: The DE is separable $(\ln u)'=\dfrac {u'}u$

Comment: @user577215664 Yes, but I remember that there was a specific formula for the integrating factor, but I forgot it

Comment: Try this for some simpler cases first. E.g. for $u'+ xu = 0$ or $u' -x^2u = 0$. Oh yeah, and look up the term *integrating factor*. In your notes, in your textbook, on the web. If you are asking this question while sitting in an exam, all of this is illegal of course and you should stop right now.

Comment: write this then integrate $(\ln u)'=\dfrac {u'}u=i(\lambda -q)$

Comment: @user577215664 thank you

Comment: you're welcome Anion